# Adding Two .swift files with same name to project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swagger

I am trying to integrate swagger client in my project. I was able to generate classes from swagger. Swagger for swift 3 uses Alamofire for its newtork operations. The issue is one of the generated class name is 'Response'. Alamofire internally has the same class. When i add these classes and try to build I have many errors complaining about re-declaration of class. What can i do in this case? Should i have to change from my server side to not get 'Response' class?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to leave their code alone and just add the module name to your calls:

```
Alamofire.Response.... Swagger.Response...
```

so that your code is not ambiguous. (the compiler won't try to guess which one you mean, and you've given it two possibilities... the Module name at the beginning of the class will make it clear to the compiler which one you want.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I was able to solve the problem by adding prefix to swagger model classes. Swagger's Response became GenResponse.

Comment: Oh. That's different from what I suggested.  The problem with your approach is if they update their code, you will have to change it again.  If you do it the way I suggested you won't have to change any code if they upgrade. But I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: If I follow your approach it does not even let me run the code. Response in Alamofire and Response in swagger has a compile time error of invalid re-declaration of class. Forget about calling, just to build the code I had to change name of swagger class

Comment: Alamofire and Swagger need to be in separate modules - that will eliminate the ambiguity.  Did you copy the files into your project, or drag the .xcodeproj files into your project? You should do the latter if you did the first, because they each need to be in their own module. If you drag the frameworks into your project that should also work correctly.